# Mysql apply coalesce to all found records

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say i have a set of relations and for each of these relations i have features.In function, i query to get all relations and all the features that are attached to that relation.Each feature has a content in some language.
If i were to have 3 features, the sample table for those feature translations would be

```
Relation1 -> F1-EN, F2-EN, F3-EN
          -> F1-DE, F2-DE,   -
          -> F1-SP,   -  , F3-SP
          -> F1-FR,   -  ,   -
Relation2 ....
```

i want to be able to get all these features according to the primary language that i am sending, sending DE as a main language i should get

F1-DE, F2-DE, F3-EN (since DE value of F3 is null)

```
-- get relation fields --,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT coalesce(ft2.name, ft1.name) SEPARATOR ',') AS features

FROM 'relations'

LEFT JOIN 'feature_translations' ft1 ON relations.feature_id = 
ft1.feature_id
LEFT JOIN 'feature_translations' ft2 ON relations.feature_id = 
ft2.feature_id AND ft2.language_id = 'FR'

GROUP BY relations.relation_id
```

with this, im only able to get (F1-FR) because coalesce return the first non null value, but i want  all of the features F1-FR, F2-EN, F3-EN

Comment: sample data is not understandable can you put in tabular format

Comment: i have 3 features, these feature may or may not be in every language, so for English language i have F1,F2,F3 in english, for German i have F1 and F3 (F2 is null for german).

so for the null translations, i desire to get english version.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I've tried to reproduce your problem with [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc8e89/8) ('DE' as main language).

You likely need two groupings

```
SELECT f.relation_id, GROUP_CONCAT(f.feature) as features 
FROM
  (SELECT relations.relation_id, coalesce(ft1.name, ft2.name) AS feature
   FROM relations
     LEFT JOIN feature_translations ft1 ON relations.feature_id =
                                           ft1.feature_id AND ft1.language_id = 'DE'
     LEFT JOIN feature_translations ft2 ON relations.feature_id =
                                           ft2.feature_id AND ft2.language_id != 'DE'
   GROUP BY relations.relation_id, relations.feature_id) as f
GROUP BY f.relation_id;
```

Comment: your solution gives me F1-FR, F1-FR, F1-FR i mean all feature's names are the same